# TestNG. Change testng-results to not include configuration methods

Tags: java, maven, logging, configuration, testng

I'm trying to reconfigure my test results to not show skip results for configuration methods & is skews my data.

I'm running tests through TestNG where each method has a @beforeMethod and @afterMethod configuration method. In the beforeMethod I check whether a @Test method should run or not & if not I throw a SkipException to skip it.

---

In my current situation I have 2 test methods I run. One is made to fail and the other is designed to be skipped. So I expect to get a result of 1 fail and 1 skip. In the IDE console this is the result I get, but when I run it through Maven I get 1 fail and 3 skips. Here is my [emailable-result.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sywhx.jpg). The failed test case has no @beforeMethod or @afterMethod showing.

I found out about the IConfigurationListener but I am not sure how to use it to remove a configuration method from the report. I am also using maven surefire

This is what I have so far.

```
public class MyConfigurationListenerAdapter implements IConfigurationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSkip(ITestResult itr) {
        String configName = itr.getName();
        if (configName.equals("beforeMethod")||configName.equals("afterMethod")){
            //TODO remove itr from test result
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.14.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <properties>
               <property>
                   <name>listener</name>
                   <value>java_accelerator.testng.classes.MyConfigurationListenerAdapter</value>
               </property>
           </properties>
           <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
           <suiteXmlFiles>
              <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/testclasses/tests/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
           </suiteXmlFiles>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Anyone able to help me from here?